# AngularJS ng-class the same class with different conditions

Tags: angularjs

I have a option in the back-end to let user change icon in default and in hover state. This is the code

```
ng-class="{'{{getAnswerButtonHoverIcon()}}':hovering, '{{getAnswerButtonIcon()}}' : !hovering}
```

But the problem is, when the user selected the same icon for default state and hover state, like for example they have selected "fa-circle-o" the output of the HTML will be

```
ng-class="{'fa-circle-o':hovering, 'fa-circle-o' : !hovering}"
```

and it doesn't work anymore. When I try to test it out, it removes the "fa-cricle-o" class on hover. Any idea why is it happening? And if you can suggest better solution, it will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: would merging the two functions be an option for you? Now you have getAnswerButtonHoverIcon() and getAnswerButtonIcon() which could be getIcon(hover) which returns only one string that is your desired class. Would it be feasible with your backend?

Comment: well that's a great suggestion. thank you, but it doesn't solved the problem. I still have to use two conditions in ng-class, get icon for default, and get icon for hover. if the function will have the same output, the problem still persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned in a comment that I would probably have a single function but I think I misunderstood your question at first. Building on Joshua's approach here is something that could work for you: if the two functions return the same value then it still works.

I feel that this is not the nicest solution since it is generating a string into a class, but the same can be changed to ng-class and {hovering ? sg() : sgelse()} as value. I hope it shows you a way to handle these kind of interactions.

Let me know if it does/doesn't work so that we could further help you.

```js
var app = angular.module("mainModule",[]);

app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.icon = {};
  $scope.icon.hovering = false;
  
  $scope.getAnswerButtonHoverIcon = function(){
    return 'bluebg';
  };
  
  $scope.getAnswerButtonIcon = function(){
    return 'redbg';
  };
  
});
```

```css
.bluebg{background-color:blue}
.redbg{background-color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="mainModule">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div  class="{{ icon.hovering ? getAnswerButtonHoverIcon() : getAnswerButtonIcon() }}"
          ng-mouseenter="icon.hovering = true" ng-mouseleave="icon.hovering = false">
      <p>I have different backgrounds</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the ng-class like this, which will just apply the class the function outputs:

```
ng-class="(hovering ? '{{getAnswerButtonHoverIcon()}}': '{{getAnswerButtonIcon()}}')
```